# GCP: Is there a way to have both the OPS Agent and the Legacy Agent installed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fluentd, google-cloud-logging, fluent-bit

My current set up uses the legacy logging agent (google-fluentd), so all my logging is configured for fluentd. I am supposed to switch to the OPS Agent, which uses fluent bit, therefore a different configuration for the logging.

Is there any way to have both google-fluentd and the ops agent running, or is there an easy way to move the fluentd config to fluent bit? The reason why having both would help is to do a quick switch over when the configuration has been changed, but at the time it is not possible as the agents conflict with each other.

Answer (score 3):

Currently both logging agent can't co-exist. Ops agent strictly prevents logging and monitoring agents from starting if the legacy agents are installed.

There is already an ongoing Feature request for a workaround similar to your use case. I recommend that you upvote and follow the case below for future updates:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218671982

This [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/pull/74#issuecomment-966678204) also has something to do with the use case.